Are there ways to achieve a similar effect to replacing a parent class?
In order to use the entry framework in multiple DB engines, we inherit and implement it as follows.
(Only migrations are created differently for each DB)

Image Name : DataSet - ModelsDbContextModel source code here
//Image Name : DataSet
public class ModelsDbContextModel : DbContext
{

    public ModelsDbContextModel()
    {
    }

    public ModelsDbContextModel(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestOC1> TestOC1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestOC2> TestOC2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TestOC3> TestOC3 { get; set; }

}


Image Name : Migration_Common - ModelsDbContext source code here
//Image Name : Migration_Common
//
//GlobalDb.DBType : DB name to use
//GlobalDb.DBString : Connection string of DB to use
public class ModelsDbContext: ModelsDbContextModel
{
    public ModelsDbContext()
    {
    }
    public ModelsDbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        switch (GlobalDb.DBType)
        {
            case "SQLite":
                options.UseSqlite(GlobalDb.DBString);
                break;
            case "MSSQL":
                options.UseSqlServer(GlobalDb.DBString);
                break;

            case "InMemory":
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(GlobalDb.DBString);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}



Image Name : Migration_Sqlite - ModelsDbContext_Sqlite source code here
//Image Name : Migration_Sqlite
public class ModelsDbContext_Sqlite : ModelsDbContext
{
    public ModelsDbContext_Sqlite(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        GlobalDb.DBType = "SQLite";
        GlobalDb.DBString = "Data Source=Test.db";
    }

    public ModelsDbContext_Sqlite()
    {
    }
}


public class ModelsDbContext_SqliteFactory
    : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ModelsDbContext_Sqlite>
{
    public ModelsDbContext_Sqlite CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext> optionsBuilder
            = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();

        return new ModelsDbContext_Sqlite(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}


Image Name : Migration_Mssql - ModelsDbContext_Mssql source code here
//Image Name : Migration_Mssql
public class ModelsDbContext_Mssql : ModelsDbContext
{
    public ModelsDbContext_Mssql(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        GlobalDb.DBType = "MSSQL";
        GlobalDb.DBString = "";
    }
    public ModelsDbContext_Mssql()
    {
    }
}

public class ModelsDbContext_MssqlFactory
    : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ModelsDbContext_Mssql>
{
    public ModelsDbContext_Mssql CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext> optionsBuilder
            = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();

        return new ModelsDbContext_Mssql(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}


//Sqlite Create migration command
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context ModelsDbContext_Sqlite -OutputDir Migrations/Sqlite

//Mssql Create migration command
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context ModelsDbContext_Mssql -OutputDir Migrations/Mssql 


//use DbContext
using (ModelsDbContext db1 = new ModelsDbContext())
{
    TestOC1? findItem = db1.TestOC1.Where(w => w.idTestOC1 == 1).FirstOrDefault();
}



Every time I create a new project, I copy part (1) to the project and then modify and use only the 'DataSet' part.


  
Since the only content that changes in this configuration is 'DataSet', I would like to convert part (2) into a library.  
However, this attempt failed several times.  
This attempt appears to be replacing 'DataSet', the parent of 'Migration_Common', while leaving the inheritance structure as is.  

The properties of 'DataSet' are not fixed because they function as a table.  
The approach of using only the fixed properties cannot be used due to this issue.  
(Examples: Interfaces, abstract classes, wrappers, etc.)  

If you have 'DataSet' or 'Migration_Common' as instances instead of inheriting them, you cannot inherit 'DbContext' and therefore cannot use the migration command.  


If possible, I would like to be able to use only 'DataSet' by replacing it.  
Any method is fine as long as it allows me to use the migration command and also replace the contents of the 'DataSet'.  
I would appreciate any ideas you may have.

I may have implemented the method incorrectly or misunderstood it. 
I would appreciate it if you could point out any errors in my implementation or understanding.  


Test project here

* that the green names in the image are the class names in the test project.

* The migration commands are commented out in the file 'DbContexts > ModelsDbContext_[DB Name].cs'.

* To migrate 'MSSQL', you must have a 'SettingInfo_gitignore.json' file in your project root.
This file contains important information, so it was not uploaded to github.)
The file contents are as follows.
    [
      {
        "DBTypeString": "MSSQL",
        "DBString": "[MSSQL connect string]"
      }
    ]


Is your DataSet inheriting from DbContext? And your migrations from the DataSet? Why? I have never seen this approach. To handle different providers I would have expected something like runtime checks where needed, or possibly different dbContexts sharing entity classes. Copying classes to different projects also sound wrong to me.

@DarkBee The linked test project is not intended to be used to complete the question.
The project is provided in advance so that respondents can quickly construct a project and implement their ideas.
Should I also include code for configuring the project that is unrelated to the question in the body?

@JonasH The parent of 'DataSet' is 'DbContext'.
This is a method to respond to multiple DBs using the same 'DataSet'.
If migrations are created for each DB engine, you can select and use the desired DB engine in the built project by simply selecting the provider.
This way, there is no need to build for each DB engine.

@JonasH I may be approaching this the wrong way(I'm using it well, but that's not the point.)
If there are other approaches to replacing multiple DB providers without a build, I would appreciate it if you could let me know

See how to switch db provider from configuration. Most things should just work with any provider, just be careful to avoid provider specific features. And write automated tests of your db code.

@JonasH The link you provided is how to select a provider when injecting dependencies.
(The code that plays this role is included in the source code (ModelsDbContext) added to the main text.)
My code can also be used to inject dependencies (just specify DbContext as ModelsDbContext).
